# How do I remove players I don't use from the sound indicator?

Tags: indicator, indicator-sound

how to remove installed Xnoise, rhytmbox on my sound indicator?
I am not using these 2 music player anymore
I want to remove it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently, the only way to do this is to edit the seendb txt file that the menu uses to keep track of interested players.

Open terminal and type:

```
gedit ~/.cache/indicators/sound/familiar-players-db.keyfile
```

This will launch the familiar text editor where you will see something like

```
DesktopFiles=/usr/share/applications/banshee-1.desktop;/usr/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop;
```

Remove the rhythmbox and xnoise entries

and leave it looking something like

```
[Seen Database]
DesktopFiles=/usr/share/applications/banshee-1.desktop;
```

Save, then reload indicator-applet on the panel.

Answer (score 16):

Rather than blacklist the entry, it can be removed from the list.

Try the following:

```
kch:~$ gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players
['banshee', 'rhythmbox']
```

This shows I have two entries. To remove one, use the `set` option:

```
kch:~$ gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players "['rhythmbox']"
```

Note the quotes around the value to be inserted.

Now restart or logout, and the entry should be gone from your sound menu.

Comment: This works like a charm on 11.10 Oneiric

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. i had gnome-mplayer stuck in there after uninstall and this method solved that issue for me! thanks!

Comment: you may still want to blacklist as i found rhythmbox somehow ended up appearing in the list again, despite me removing it

Answer (score 5):

### 12.04

If you wish to hide or 'blacklist' a media player from the sound indicator, you will first need to make sure if the sound indicator settings have media players already blacklisted:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.sound blacklisted-media-players
```

If no other players have been blacklisted, you will not have to worry about adding them to the command below. If you do have other media players, you will need to copy those players into the below command and add any other players you want to backlist.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound blacklisted-media-players "['<mediaplayer>','<mediaplayer']"
```

Here is an example of how to blacklist spotify from the sound indicator:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.sound blacklisted-media-players
['']

gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound blacklisted-media-players "['spotify']"

gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.sound blacklisted-media-players
['spotify']
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answer didnt work for me with 11.04 Natty Narwhal I looked for another way. For example to remove rhythmbox from the sound-menue the following command in terminal worked:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound blacklisted-media-players "['rhythmbox']"
```