# Hide program entry's in sound indicator

Tags: indicator, music, indicator-sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove players I don't use from the sound indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12867/how-do-i-remove-players-i-dont-use-from-the-sound-indicator)

How to hide the entry of programs in the sound indicator, Ubuntu 12.04 (Spotify, VLC)

Thanks