# How can I integrate DeadBeef into the sound indicator menu?

Tags: unity, indicator-sound, deadbeef

Is it a way to put DeadBeef to sound menu instead of Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

**how to**

First install deadbeef - you should check the [authors launchpad website](https://launchpad.net/~alexey-smirnov/+archive/deadbeef) for precompiled versions of deadbeef.  At the time of writing this, no 12.10 or later version was available:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexey-smirnov/deadbeef
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install deadbeef
```

**add deadbeef to sound indicator**

Using `dconf-editor` you can add deadbeef to the sound indicator:

[image]

**add volume control options**

To add the volume controls you need to compile from the MPRIS plugin from source.

*important note* - this was highly unstable for me on 64bit ubuntu causing deadbeef to continually crash and I dont recommend you do so.

sudo apt-get install deadbeef-plugins-dev git

Next download the [mpris plugin source](https://github.com/kernelhcy/DeaDBeeF-MPRIS-plugin) from github

```
git clone https://github.com/kernelhcy/DeaDBeeF-MPRIS-plugin.git
cd DeaDBeeF-MPRIS-plugin
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If you want to remove Rhythmbox from the sound indicator then the linked Q&A will help

---

Linked Questions:

- [How do I change the Sound Menu's default music player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37158/how-do-i-change-the-sound-menus-default-music-player)
- [How do I remove players I don't use from the sound indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12867/how-do-i-remove-players-i-dont-use-from-the-sound-indicator)

Comment: Your instructions are out-of-date. The PPA does not support 12.10 and the MPRIS plugin is no longer available on SourceForge. Can you please update your post with a working method to install the MPRIS plugin?

Comment: @Dune - updated - however you should note, no 12.10 version exists.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I can help it I don't want to build this plugin from source. If you've already built the plugin, would you mind uploading the `.so` file somewhere? I am using the x64 version of DeadBeeF on 12.10 x64.

Comment: Does this still work? I noticed this answer is 8 years old, I want to make sure it's not obsolete before I screw with the dconf.